# UncaughtException: connect ETIMEDOUT in Node JS

Tags: node.js, exception, uncaught-exception

Error :

```
 error: uncaughtException: connect ETIMEDOUT date=Wed Jan 14 2015
 23:12:29 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=2397, uid=1000, gid=1000,
 cwd=/home/user/node/workingcopy/server_dev, execPath=/usr/bin/nodejs,
 version=v0.10.33,
 argv=[nodejs, /home/user/node/workingcopy/server_dev/app.js], rss=69976064,
 heapTotal=63359488, heapUsed=38560856, loadavg=[0.19091796875,
 0.4814453125, 0.439453125], uptime=189505.245376888,
 trace=[column=11, le=net.js, function=errnoException, line=904,
 method=null,
 native=false, column=19, file=net.js, function=Object.afterConnect [as
 oncomplete], line=895, method=afterConnect [as oncomplete],
 native=false], stack=[Error: connect ETIMEDOUT,     at errnoException
 (net.js:904:11),     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
 (net.js:895:19)]
```

How can we avoid server crash on this exception.?

Comment: Attach an `"error"` event listener to the stream